# Не работает преобразование стилей в Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Я изучал Webpack и решил создать свою сборку но я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Webpack ругается на то что мне нужен другой loader но я его подключил как видно с файла webpack.config.js:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let path = require('path');

let conf = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./dist'),
        filename:'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devServer:{
        overlay: true
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
     ]
};

module.export = (env,options) => {
    let production = options.mode === 'production';

    conf.devtool = production 
                                    ? 'source-map' 
                                    : 'eval-sourcemap';
    return conf;
};
```

Подскажите как решить эту проблему.

```
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
        "build": "webpack --mode development",
        "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: а `package.json` есть посмотреть?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос!